# Close ul list on leaving field (click or using tab on keyboard)

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

complete list which is as follows-

```
<div class="autocomplete-list1">
    <input type="text" class="addpropertyinput areaname-list-completed" name="property_areaname" id="property_areaname" placeholder="Area Name" onkeyup="autofillareaname()" maxlength="40" required />
    <ul class="areaname-list" id="property_areaname_list"></ul>
</div>
<div class="errormsg" id="errormsg9"></div>
```

I can get the list to be closed with clicked anywhere outside the page

```
$(window).click(function() {
$('#property_areaname_list').hide();
});

$('#property_areaname_list').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

but how to close the list if tab is pressed on keyboard, if i use blur event then it closes but any selection clicked on the list does not get selected...

Comment: Make sure the id is correct because you are using "property_areaname" in HTML and using "property_areaname_list" in the JS code.

Comment: @Nitesh  is right here DragonFire

Comment: that is for the textbox, ul has id <ul class="areaname-list" id="property_areaname_list"></ul>

Comment: you can use focusout or blur on input field to hide the ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hide list on tab click:-***

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
   $('#property_areaname_list').hide();
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="autocomplete-list1">
    <input type="text" class="addpropertyinput areaname-list-completed" name="property_areaname" id="property_areaname" placeholder="Area Name" onkeyup="autofillareaname()" maxlength="40" required />
    <ul class="areaname-list" id="property_areaname_list"><li>1</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="errormsg" id="errormsg9"></div>
```

Note:-

When any key is pressed, this above code will check the key-code of that key and if key-code is 9 means ***`tab key`*** is pressed. then it will hide the auto-complete list

Comment: thanks Anant... could you do a slight explanation of what is happening here.. i know it may be too much to ask..

Comment: @DragonFire  i have added the explanation in my answer.Check once

Answer (score 1):

use key press like..it may work

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 9) { 
    $('#property_areaname_list').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            alert("hi");
        }
    });

Comment: 13 is enter key if you need tab key use 9

Answer (score 1):

hide the div with lost focus or blur

```
$("#property_areaname").focusout(function() {
        $('#property_areaname_list').hide();
    });
```

with animation

```
$("#property_areaname").focusout(function() {
    $('#property_areaname_list').animate({
        display:"none"
    });
});
```

Comment: as i pointed out in my question... this will not enable selection of the list item